# Error by using Rinno to deploy R shiny app as a standalone application

Tags: r, shiny

I applied [Rinno](https://www.ficonsulting.com/filabs/RInno) to make an executable Shiny-App which should work locally. However, after running `setup_myapp.exe` to generate an executable app I got an [image: error]!

Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: maybe behind proxy?

Answer (score 1):

This error is generated when the app cannot connect to the internet. Unless you package all of the dependencies into the RInno installation, the app needs an internet connection to install them from CRAN. It can also be caused by company firewall policies or simply an offline computer.

In RInno 0.3.0 or greater, this error is resolved because it will package all dependencies as windows binaries and deliver them with the .exe (no need for an internet connection on the installing computer).